# Consequence of Chebotarev's density theorem

Tags: number-theory, polynomials, galois-theory, algebraic-number-theory, finite-fields

I'm studying Chatzidakis Notes about pseudo-finite fields. During a proof she states the following (by $\mathbb{F}_p$ I mean the finite field with $p$ elements for a prime $p$):

Let $f_1(x),\ldots,f_m(x),g(x) \in \mathbb{Z}[x]$ and let $L$ be the Galois extension of $\mathbb{Q}$ obtained by adjoining all the roots of the polynomials $f_i (x)$. Assume that there is a subfield $M$ of $L$ such that $Gal(L/M)$ is cyclic and

$$M \vDash \bigwedge_{i=1} ^m \exists t f_i(t) = 0 \wedge \forall t g(t) \ne 0.$$
Then the set of prime numbers $p$ such that $\mathbb{F}_p \vDash \bigwedge_{i=1} ^m \exists t f_i(t) = 0 \wedge \forall t g(t) \ne 0$ is infinite.

She claims that the latter is a consequence of Chebotarev's Density Theorem. I understand that by a corollary of Frobenius Theorem, the number of primes $p$ such that each polynomial $f_i(x)$ has a root modulo $p$ is infinite. But what about the polynomial $g(x)$?

I don't understand how to derive the latter from Chebotarev's Theorem.

Comment: Your notations are ridiculous. Are you looking at the primes such that each $f_i$ has a root in $\Bbb{F}_p$ which is not a root of $g$ ? If not then what did you mean (try with $f_i=x,L=M=\Bbb{Q}$ then $ g=(x^2-2)(x^2-3)(x^2-6)$ always has a root in $\Bbb{F}_p$)

Comment: Maybe you meant $L$ is the splitting field of $g \prod_i f_i$ ? In that case with $a_j $ the roots of $g$ then $g$ has no root in $\Bbb{F}_p$ and $p$ is unramified means that for all prime $j$ and $\mathfrak{p}/p\in L$ then $a_j^p-a_j\not \in \mathfrak{p}$ ie. $Frob_\mathfrak{p} \not \in Gal(L/\Bbb{Q}(a_j))$.

Comment: The result I don't understand is 3.11 at the end of page 15 in https://www.math.ens.fr/~zchatzid/papiers/Singapore.pdf which is stated exactly in that way. Maybe there is a mistake in the statement